# C# Calling an overriden method within the superclass

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, xna

Hey there. I just picked up C# to learn game programming with XNA, but I also have some experience in Java.

Here's my code, in essence:

```
public class A
{
    public Rectangle getRectangle()
    {
        return [some rectangle];
    }

    public bool collision(A other)
    {
        Rectangle rect1 = getRectangle();
        Rectangle rect2 = other.getRectangle();
        return rect1.Intersects(rect2);
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public Rectangle getRectangle()
    {
        return [some other rectangle];
    }
}
```

The problem arises when I try something like this:

```
A a;
B b;
if(a.collision(b))
    ...
```

Where B's version of get rectangle is never actually called, as far as I can tell. 
I tried a solution like the one suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390326/c-calling-overridden-subclass-methods-without-knowledge-that-its-a-subclass-ins)
but the message I get is basically "B.getRectangle() hides inherited member A.getRectangle(). Use the new keyword if this was intended."

I appreciate in advance any help I receive. I'm thinking my past java experience is getting in the way of understanding how C# is different. I guess if anyone just knows of a good link that explains the differences between C# and java or just how C# works in this respect that could suffice.

Cheers.

Comment: Look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744528/method-overloads-resolution-and-jon-skeets-brain-teasers

Answer (score 6):

Unlike Java, methods in C# are *not* marked virtual by default. What your current code is doing is *hiding* the `getRectangle` method: there is an implicit `new` modifier on the declaration of the method in the derived class.

You need to explicitly include the `virtual` modifier in the method-declaration in the base class:

```
public virtual Rectangle getRectangle() { ... }
```

and `override` it in the derived class with:

```
public override Rectangle getRectangle() { ... }
```

Comment: Props for the implicit new. I didn't realize the language did that.

Comment: @Ritch: It's a conceptual thing. You don't have to think of it that way - it's just a way of avoiding the 'brittle base-class' problem.

Comment: I just assumed it wouldn't compile. I use resharper, so I've never tried either.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the keyword `override` for the `getRectangle` method in class B like so:

```
public override Rectangle getRectangle()
```

Comment: Such a solution makes me feel silly. I'll give inheritance in C# a more in depth look before asking this kind of question again. Probably could have given the debugging a better try, too.

Thanks.

Comment: @DevynS: Your welcome. Please mark this as the answer and/or upvote if it helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Java, but I assume they have some sort of virtual/override syntax for methods?

```
  public class A
  {
    virtual public Rectangle getRectangle()
    {
      return [some rectangle];
    }

    public bool collision(A other)
    {
      Rectangle rect1 = getRectangle();
      Rectangle rect2 = other.getRectangle();
      return rect1.Intersects(rect2);
    }
  }

  public class B : A
  {
     override public Rectangle getRectangle()
     { 
        return [some other rectangle];
     }
   }
```

Comment: "but I assume they have some sort of virtual/override syntax". No Java has implicit virtual and override. So all methods are virtual and method of same name always acts as override.

Comment: Oh wow. I figured they were somewhere between C++ virtual, and C#'s virtual, new, override, abstract overkill.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use Override to change the functionality of getRectangle() in B.